# Hash Function for Strings

Tags: string, algorithm, hash

I need a hash function for a string (of bytes) that

1. Has a low collision ratio (even for short strings)
2. Can be computed quickly (`O(n)` time is a must but I want it as fast as possible)
3. Given `hash(string1)` and `hash(string2)`, computing `hash(append(string1, string2))`
           can be done in `O(1)`.

The best I could come up with so far is this:  (in Java pseudocode)

```java
public static int[] HASH_ENTROPY = new int[] {...} // 255 large prime numbers

public int hash()
    int hash = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < this.array.length; i++)
       hash += HASH_ENTROPY[this.array[i] + 128];
    return hash;
```

Are there any better algorithms?   This one performs well with #1 and #3 but I'm wondering
if it's too slow having to access the random elements in the array.

Comment: This is not dissimilar to RSA and other similar approaches, instead of just 'large' primes, you could use primes that are relatively prime to a lot of things (i.e. 3, 17, etc.) I know Ramanujan also came up with a very good number for hashing (can't think of it off the top of my head.)

Comment: That algorithm is order-independent, which means that anagrams will collide; that seems to contradict desire #1, although it's tricky to get #3 to be so fast with an order-dependent hash algorithm. I really don't think the speed of looking up the entropy values matters, but on the other hand, they're not helping you much either since.

Comment: @nikdeapen For what purpose u are using Hashing (security or lookup)? What is the hash key length needed?

Comment: @VikramBhat not security, just hashmap lookup

Comment: @rici anagrams happen so rarely in application that i'm not worried about them

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use:

```
public uint32_t hash()
    uint32_t hash = 0x1f351f35; // 2x Barker code
    for (int i=0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
       char c = this.array[i];
       hash = ((hash << 1) | (hash >> 31)) + (HASH_ENTROPY[(uint8_t)(hash + c)] ^ c);
    }
    return hash;
```

Comment: This works good but it is about 4-5 times slower than the one I gave.  Is there any substantial benefit to using this function instead?

Comment: benefits - resistible to anagrams hash("ab") != hash("ba"); Snowcrash effect, when change 1 bit in the input data changes ~50% bits in output.

Comment: How you will do: *Given `hash(string1)` and `hash(string2)`, computing `hash(append(string1, string2))` can be done in O(1).* ?

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you need quick computing time, you can consider another hash function:

```
public uint32_t hash()
    uint32_t hash = 0x1f351f35; // 2x Barker code
    for (int i=0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
       hash += (hash << 4) + this.array[i];
    }
    return hash;
```

Important:
Previous hash function uses entropy array; you can populate this array by random values at each program start, so there will be universal hashing, resistant from external attack, when somebody outside especially generates many strings with same hash, for produce collision and DOS of your service. This function is quick, but isn't resistible for evil attack.